# Generate a timestamp when inserting a row

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add a datetime column which purpose should be to give an exact time on when a row inserted. At the moment this is done in a MERGE statement from a view to a table. The issue is that the merge statement clumps all the merges into the same datetime.

I do wonder if there is a way to add the current_datetime to a row-by-row load basis? An expected result could be as below, if it takes 0.001 seconds to load a new row:

| ID | LOAD TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-05-24 17:34:21.000 |
| 456 | 2021-05-24 17:34:21.001 |

The issue I have today is that all of the LOAD TIME rows that are merged in the same statement have the same LOAD TIME. Is that simply how the MERGE statement works? Are there other ways to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `current_timestamp` works in Snowflake. It takes the start time of the transaction, not the wallclock time. Since the Merge runs atomically all of the rows get the same timestamp (this is normally what you want).

In Postgres, there is a `timeofday()` function that would do this, I don't believe there is an equivalent in Snowflake however.